# How to get Firebase user uuid

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase

Is there any way to get **Firebase** user **uuid** when user is logged out, but was logged in at least once as a **anonymous**?Maybe its possible to get **uuid** from **keychain** access or from Firebase **userDefaults**?

Answer (score 2):

You can only get the UID if there is a current `[FIRAuth auth].currentUser`. Any other 'hacky' method to try and retrieve this would not be recommended.

If you wanted to get this after they had logged out you could save this into `UserDefaults` or the keychain yourself while they are logged in.

Answer (score 1):

You can get it by:

```
FIRUser *user = [FIRAuth auth].currentUser;
if (user) {
  NSString *uid = user.uid;
}
```

Hope this help.

Comment: And I need to get uuid when user was logged in, but currently logged out

Comment: you have to authenticate the user. If you want to get the firebase `uid`. Logout will stop the user session! Either you can save `uid` in `userDefaults` or send it your server So that you can get it later on using **API** call.

Comment: Yea I have it on database, problem is that I don't have how to pull it from there because it is associated with phone number wich I cannot get it anyhow